# Failing to catch errors thrown by a redux-saga call()ing another saga

Tags: react-native, error-handling, redux, redux-saga

So let's say I have one saga:

`export function * initSignUp (action) {
  try {
    yield call(signUp, action.signUpDetails)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('caught in initSignUp', err)
    yield put({ type: 'SIGN_UP_FAIL', err, action })
  }
}`

which is calling (invoking? queueing?) another:

`export function * signUp (action) {
  try {
    let response = yield Auth.signUp({...})
    yield put(addData({...}))

  } catch (err) {
    console.log('caught in signUp', err)
    throw new Error(err)
  }
}`

If the inner saga here fails on `yield Auth.signUp()` then the first catch block is hit, but throwing the error results in an uncaught exception.

I have tried both `throw new Error(err)` and `return Promise.reject(err)` and while the latter fails more gracefully, I still never hit the 'caught in initSignUp' line.

Why can't I `catch` this error in `initSignUp()` ?

edit:

initSignUp is called like this:

`function * onboardingSaga () {
  yield all([
    takeEvery(INIT_SIGN_UP, initSignUp),
    ...`

and signUp:

`function * authSaga () {
  yield all([

    takeEvery(SIGN_UP, signUp),
    ...`

rootSaga:

`export default function * rootSaga () {
  yield all([
    OnboardingSaga(),
    AuthSaga()
  ])
}`

Stacktrace:

```
[14:04:16] uncaught at rootSaga, at rootSaga                                                                                               
 at rootSaga                                                                                                                               
 at takeEvery                                                                                                                              
 at signUp                                                                                                                                 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined                                                                                   
    at signUp$ (blob:http://192.168.178.27:19001/d74267c7-c785-4744-a144-ed0c708da730:224959:89)                                           
    at tryCatch (blob:http://192.168.178.27:19001/d74267c7-c785-4744-a144-ed0c708da730:20888:19)                                           
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (blob:http://192.168.178.27:19001/d74267c7-c785-4744-a144-ed0c708da730:21063:24)                      
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (blob:http://192.168.178.27:19001/d74267c7-c785-4744-a144-ed0c708da730:20931:23) 
    at next (blob:http://192.168.178.27:19001/d74267c7-c785-4744-a144-ed0c708da730:149528:29)                                              
    at proc (blob:http://192.168.178.27:19001/d74267c7-c785-4744-a144-ed0c708da730:149503:5)                                               
    at runForkEffect (blob:http://192.168.178.27:19001/d74267c7-c785-4744-a144-ed0c708da730:149744:21)                                     
    at runEffect (blob:http://192.168.178.27:19001/d74267c7-c785-4744-a144-ed0c708da730:149629:770)                                        
    at next (blob:http://192.168.178.27:19001/d74267c7-c785-4744-a144-ed0c708da730:149532:11)                                              
    at currCb (blob:http://192.168.178.27:19001/d74267c7-c785-4744-a144-ed0c708da730:149606:9)                                             
- node_modules\expo\build\logs\LogSerialization.js:145:14 in _captureConsoleStackTrace                                                     
- node_modules\expo\build\logs\LogSerialization.js:40:24 in Object.serializeLogDataAsync$                                                  
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`call()`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callcontext-fnname-args):

```
let response = yield call([Auth, signUp], {...})
```

Redux-saga expects declarative [effects](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.html) to be yielded.

You can't directly yield a promise (Auth.signUp returns a promise, I suppose), you should wrap it in a `call()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still getting `uncaught at rootSaga, at takeEvery, at signUp ...`

Comment: @edzillion I don't see a `takeEvery()` in your code, but it is present in this stack trace. Your `signUp()` saga must be called from somewhere else with `takeEvery()`. Track down that `takeEvery` and add full error (with stack trace) to the question.

Comment: ok I have added the `takeEvery` parts and the full stack trace. I actually think I should be using `take` instead of `takeEvery` as we only want one signUp happening at once.

Comment: Well, you actually have `Cannot read property 'username' of undefined` at `signUp()` when it's being called from `takeEvery()`. Sorry, can't help with the code much further.